# How to get struct field having pointer to the struct?

Tags: c, struct

I have two structs:

```
struct first
{
    int* array;
}

struct second
{
    struct first* firsts;
} *SECOND;
```

Let's say somewhere I can get the address of one of `struct first` from `SECOND->firsts` by its index.
How could I get `array` of this struct? I've tried

```
SECOND->firsts[index]->array
```

but there is `expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type` error.

Comment: You need to show the declaration of `ptr_to_struct`. Show the relevant code  instead of describing it. All that can be said with the information you provide is: _the type of `ptr_to_struct` is not `struct first*`_

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I get it by index ```ptr_to_struct = second->firsts[index]```. Actually, I need to ```SECOND->firsts[index]->array```

Comment: Please don't put code in a comment, but [edit]  your question and put all relevant information _there_

Comment: @PavelAntspovich With `ptr_to_struct = second->firsts[index]` you should get a compiler error if `ptr_to_struct` is declared as a pointer because `second->firsts[index]` is of type `struct first`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No malloc checks and no free - just to show the idea

```
struct first {
    int* array; };

struct second {
    struct first* firsts; } *SECOND;

#define NUMFIRSTS   50
#define ARRSIZE 50

int main() {
    SECOND = malloc(sizeof(*SECOND));
    SECOND -> firsts = malloc(NUMFIRSTS * sizeof(*SECOND -> firsts));
    for(int f = 0; f < NUMFIRSTS; f++)
    {
        SECOND -> firsts[f].array = malloc(ARRSIZE * sizeof(*SECOND -> firsts[f].array));
    }

    //access
    SECOND -> firsts[5].array[10] = 23; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct first
{
    int* array;
};

struct second
{
    struct first* firsts;
} *SECOND;

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 10;

    struct first f = { NULL };

    SECOND = malloc( sizeof( *SECOND ) );

    SECOND->firsts = &f;

    SECOND->firsts->array = malloc( n * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        SECOND->firsts->array[i] = ( int )i;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", SECOND->firsts->array[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", f.array[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    // ...
    // free all allocated memory

    return 0;
}
```

the program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Pay attention to that as the pointer `SECOND` contains pointer to `struct first f` that in turn contains pointer to array then the both objects points to the same memory pointed to by the pointer `array`.

Comment: first**s** means more than one

Comment: @P__J__ And what?

Comment: `SECOND->firsts = &f`it is just one corner case

Comment: @P__J__ It is a normal code demonstrative how pointers can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The array index operator `[]` has an implicit pointer dereference.  So this expression:

```
SECOND->firsts[index]
```

Has type `struct first`, not `struct first *`, which means you can't use the `->` operator on it.  You need to instead use the member selector operator `.`:

```
SECOND->firsts[index].array
```